# Wordpress Visual editor not working 4.9.6 - getting span code inside editor

Tags: wordpress, editor, visual-editor

Wordpress visual editor not working after the update 4.9.6, I am getting only HTML code in the editor, not my text as normal. And also I am not able to write anything in the visual editor while text mode working fine for me.

Here is code:

```
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; overflow: hidden; line- 
height: 0;" data-mce-type="bookmark" class="mce_SELRES_start"></span>
```

when I am clicking on the visual button then I am getting this above code.

Please, anyone, help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve it:

1. Make sure you **update the theme / TinyMCE**
2. If you have **Autoptimize** or similar plugin, i] in javascript option go to exclude scripts
       from Autoptimize and add this:
       "wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/compat3x/plugin.min.js"  | ii] also enable "Add try-catch wrapping" | iii] then
       "Save change and clear cache"
3. Clear Cache: Clear all site cache from cache plugin including **CDN & Cloudflare** (if you can't clear them from the cache plugin go to cloudflare & cdn and clear the cache manually)
4. If you have **Varnish cache** on your host, clear it as well
5. Clear your **browser cache**

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: how exactly did you solved it @AshiqueHussainAnsari ?

Comment: follow the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

same here, I have TinyMCE Advanced, might be the reason?
I tried both the new version of TinyMCE (4.7.11) and the older one (4.6.7), also tried turning it off, didn't help.

Also tried clearing cache - didn't help neither.

I saw someone suggesting this thing and it worked, I didn't try it yet because it seems to me little bit radical:

try adding define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); to your wp-config.php file just below the define('DB_HOST' line.

To do so, access your server via SFTP or FTP, or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel (consult your hosting provider’s documentation for specifics on these), and edit the file with a plain text editor.

Comment: I tried adding define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); in wp-config.php And also I deactivate all plugin and activate twenty sixteen theme then I re-install WordPress didn't help either. 

I talked to hosting provider as well nothing help.

Comment: I have the same problem but, only under Chrome, here is the first time that access the admin site. Under firefox I have no problem with this issue, the problem is that I can't create a shortcode thats why I switched to Chrome to see this nagging extra code that hides my post entry.

Comment: I notice that disabling the plugin Yoast SEO all of this extra TinyMCE desappears.